# Why can't rep from other SE sites count towards at least some rep here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

This has probably been addressed vis-a-vis stackoverflow, though I mostly hang out at gis.SE.

I posted [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/can-i-use-imapdocument-in-a-10-1-soe) question, but don't have enough rep to give it a tag.

Seems like this impedes movement of questions from other sites to CR.

My rep on another site should authorize me enough to at least create a tag here.

Comment: I had a look at the two tags you said you wanted to add in your question. I'm not familiar with ArcGIS or ArcObjecs so I googled them. According to wikipedia ArcGIS is a product suite and ArcObjects is a development environment, neither of which does sound like appropriate tags. If they were programming languages, concepts or apis then I would have added them for you, I am still willing to be persuaded though.

Comment: I'd say it falls more into the API category.  While there are many [arcobjects questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcobjects) at gis.SE, some have [expressed concern](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-is-this-site-about-really) about questions that are of a purely programming nature without anything geographical.

Comment: I've been told that ArcObjects is the largest COM library not owned by Microsoft.

Comment: @kirk, I've been told ArcObjects is largest COM library anywhere, including Microsoft. That was from an Esri staffer, a few years ago.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll add the ArcObjects tag for you.

Comment: @Brian Reichle Thanks!  @matt wilkie yeah I've noticed Esri doesn't brag about their big COM library the way they used to.

Answer (score 16):

200+ rep on other sites will give you the 100 rep bonus which is enough to do the regular things like comment and up-vote.

As for tagging, I would argue that tags are not strictly transferable and what makes a good tag on one site will not always make a good tag on another site. To that end I think its good that users need to spend some time on a site before being able to add new tags there.

So how much rep should you earn on a site to understand what makes a good tag? 49 (150 - 101) seems like a fairly small amount to me.

If there is a tag you want to use but does not yet exist, you can request it in your question or in a comment attached to the question and, if it's a reasonable tag, I'm sure someone will add it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree. While I'm not a mega superstar on any of the SE sites, I do have decent amount of rep and had a question here recently that I couldn't tag it as well as I would have liked. It seems that this site needs a lot more tags.

That said, on another SE site I use, there are a lot of dupe tags so having a higher rep before creating tags makes sense. I think that users who are "superstars" on at least one SE site obviously is competent enough to make tags on another.

Answer (score 1):

In the longer term I do think the rep needed for each privilege should be varied based upon the user's rep elsewhere on the SE Network. I.e. not extra rep over the 100 already added, but the rep gained in one SE site means more because of rep gain in total.

In the short term, newer sites should temporarily reduce the rep needed for some of the privileges, especially tag creation.

Alternatively, for the sites where it is relevant, like this one, allow existing tags to bleed from SO.

Comment: The rep requirements are [already reduced for public beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) (and all but removed for private beta). Also, Stack Overflow has a much broader scope, so I'm not keen on the idea of tags simply "bleeding" across.

Answer (score -3):

It seems like certain SE sites fit together well, SO and CR are just two sides of a coin, thus  almost any privileges you have on SO would probably be fine on CR. Thus I would suggest that for certain sites, privileges should cross, through your rep would not. Basically, you would get certain privileges unlocked before you have enough rep, simply because you have that privilege in SO.