# Add tag existing on SO, for which I have rep

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I am one of two users with a [c++-cli](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) tag badge on Stack Overflow.  I think that

1. any tag in use on SO is a good candidate for being a valid tag here and
2. a badge shows that I properly understand the meaning and scope of the tag

Therefore, I propose that creation of a tag here should, in addition to the current standards for introduction of new tags, be allowed if the user has earned a badge on that tag on any of the other programming-related SE sites (or use the requirement for wiki edits).

I know that [it's already been argued that not all tags are appropriate across sites](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/why-cant-rep-from-other-se-sites-count-towards-at-least-some-rep-here/314#314), but I think earning a badge probably demonstrates some level of understanding.  And Brian's claim that just requesting a tag in the question will get it added seems not to hold true.

Comment: See also [Would it make sense to copy (some) tag wikis from SO?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1412/34757)

Answer (score 9):

The point of having you wait until you have enough rep on this site is to make sure that you understand this site before you start creating new tags for it. The appropriate tags here are not the same as the appropriate tags on stack overflow. Hence I don't see that your prior badge is relevant.

Comment: While I agree that there are some tags (for example, `compiler-errors`, `language-lawyer`) which are much less appropriate here than on SO, I believe those are few and obvious.  Most SO-appropriate tags are also CR-appropriate tags.  And within that (95%?) overlap, they are the *same* tags, not different tags with a passing resemblance, as this answer seems to state.  So I assume you meant "the *set* of tags" is not the same.  While true, that is largely irrelevant.  What's important is that most of the same tags are appropriate.

Comment: To be succinct, the chance of someone using a tag on SO long enough to get a badge for it without also knowing whether it is relevant to reviewing code is no higher that the chance of someone earning privileges on CR while knowing nothing about the tag.

Comment: In fact, rejecting expertise from SO is likely to lead to adopting tags that the SO community has recognized are highly ambiguous.  Taxonomy of tags is not an easy thing, and the taxonomy problem is essentially the same on both sites.

Comment: @BenVoigt, if you want to raise that question, you'll need to something more than leave comments on my answer. Since I had to step down as moderator due to business, getting my attention or opinion is pretty irrelevant. Post your own answer or question on the subject.

Comment: This *is* my own question.  But I understand you are no longer a moderator.

Comment: @BenVoigt, ah! Well, I didn't notice that. You waited a really long time to respond! Regardless of whether or not its a good idea, the chances of the stackexchange developers agreeing to implement it is rather remote. They aren't generally willing to create special features for individual sites.